# UnavailableException: Servlet class is not a javax.servlet.Servlet with Jetty

Tags: java, scala, servlets, jetty, xsbt-web-plugin

The example given on the plugin page throws an exception when updated with the latest version of the jetty container and the jakarta package.

It expects old class 'javax.servlet.Servlet' not new 'jakarta.servlet.Servlet'

```
os: Ubuntu 22.10
java: openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
scala: 2.13.10
```

build.sbt

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.10"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "MyServlet"
  )

val jakartaServletApiVersion = "6.0.0"
val jettyVersion = "11.0.13"

libraryDependencies += "jakarta.servlet" % "jakarta.servlet-api" % jakartaServletApiVersion

Jetty / containerLibs := Seq("org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-runner" % jettyVersion)

enablePlugins(JettyPlugin)
```

plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "4.2.4")
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

MyServlet.scala

```
package mypackage

import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet
import jakarta.servlet.http.{HttpServlet, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse}

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = Array("/hello"))
class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
  println("HEY")

  override def doGet(req: HttpServletRequest, res: HttpServletResponse): Unit = {
    res.setContentType("text/html")

    res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")
    res.getWriter.write("""<h1>Hello, world!</h1>""")
  }
}
```

Command:

```
jetty:start
```

Exception:

> UnavailableException: Servlet class mypackage.MyServlet is not a javax.servlet.Servlet

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class mypackage.MyServlet is not a javax.servlet.Servlet
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.checkServletType(ServletHolder.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:730)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:911)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:564)
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The above works for me with one change: adding the missing `<web-app>` element to `web.xml`.  Do you have any other configuration not included above?  Which version of sbt are you using (`sbt --launcher-version`)?

Comment: Doesn't jetty need a more recent version to handle Jakarta packages instead of javax?

Comment: Just a clue. Jetty uses `javax` package before and is upgraded to `jakarta` later. So I think there is a mix of usage in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You have a mix of Jetty versions present in your classpath on your project.

Align them all to one version.

Not sure what your build tooling is like, but Jetty offers a [jetty-bom](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-bom) that can help you align your versions of Jetty artifacts, regardless of where they come from in your build (eg: transitive dependencies)

Jetty 11.0.13 uses Jakarta Servlet 5.0, not 6.0

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-11.0.13/pom.xml#L65

Also, do not use jetty-runner in your build tooling, it's a deprecated concept and is only meant for command line usage of the simplest webapps.

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-11.0.13/jetty-runner/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/runner/Runner.java#L68-L70

Use jetty-home and a separate jetty-base properly instead.